# What is the reference in the scene where the husband says "I don't mind at all"?

Tags: danna-wakaranai-ken

In episode 8, there was a scene of the husband saying "I don't mind at all" at the begining of the episode, with a deep voice and muscular face.

[image]

What is the reference in this scene?

Comment: It happens again about halfway through the episode, when Kaoru says they should play a game, and the husband replies "Me too" with that same face.

Answer (score 9):

By searching for the phrase that the husband is saying 私【わたし｝は一向{いっこう】に構｛かま｝わん. This image turns up in the search:

[image]

<sup>From http://diarynote.jp/data/blogs/l/20081228/75450_200812280302078062_1.jpg</sup>

The striking resemblance in the style of jaw muscles is enough to confirm the reference.

These entries on [Japanese Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%83%88%E6%B5%B7%E7%8E%8B) and [Nico Nico Pedia](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E7%83%88%E6%B5%B7%E7%8E%8B) confirms that he is Retsu Kaioh （烈海王） from [Baki the Grappler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baki_the_Grappler) （[グラップラー刃牙](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E5%88%83%E7%89%99)）.

Regarding his habit of saying "I don't mind at all!" (わたしは一向にかまわんッッ), from the [Japanese Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%83%88%E6%B5%B7%E7%8E%8B):

> 劇中の登場人物の中でも、自己鍛錬や強敵との戦いに対する執念の度合いは屈指のレベルを有し、傍目には無謀な挑戦を持ちかけられても「わたしは一向に構わん」と返答するのが口癖と化しているが、これは彼自身の性格や性情のみならず、まだ「海王」の称号を頂く以前に起こった出来事にも起因している節がある。

Rough translation:

> Even among the characters in the story, he possesses an extreme obsession for self-training and fighting against formidable opponent. Although it has become a habit for him to recklessly reply with "I don't mind at all" when approached with a challenge, objectively speaking, this does not only comes from his own personality and nature, but also comes from a principle he started before he got his Kaioh (海王 *Sea King*) title.